# How to delegate to a protocol with optional methods in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have a protocol named `MyProtocol` with an optional method named `opt()`:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func req() -> Int;

    optional func opt() -> Int;
}
```

I also have a wrapper class named `MyProtocolWrapper`:

```
@objc class ProtocolWrapper : NSObject, MyProtocol{
    let delegate : MyProtocol

    init(delegate : MyProtocol){
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func req() -> Int {
        //doSomeWorkBeforeReq
        let r = delegate.req()
        //doSomeWorkAfterReq
        return r
    }

    func opt() -> Int {
        return delegate.opt?() //compiler error because Int? is required as return type
    }

}
```

In method `ProtocolWrapper.opt()`, how can I return the optional value that may be returned by `delegate.opt?()` and still conform to `MyProtocol` protocol?

Thank you for your help,

Jair Jr

Comment: You can provide a default value `delegate.opt?() ?? 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't provide a default value because it should be provided by the user of `MyProtocol` if `opt()` returns an optional value.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 possible solutions:

1. Make result of optional method also optional, so you should replace `optional func opt() -> Int` with `optional func opt() -> Int?`
2. Return default value from `ProtocolWrapper`. Replace `return delegate.opt?()` with return `delegate.opt?() ?? 0`. `0` is just for example.
3. (I prefer this option) Create pure swift protocol and implement extension.

Replace

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func req() -> Int;

    optional func opt() -> Int;
}
```

with

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func req() -> Int

    func opt() -> Int
}

extension MyProtocol {
    //default implementation here
    func opt() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

P.S. If you inherit from `NSObject` you do not need to write `@objc` before class

P.P.S. If you use option 3 you can create pure swift class(without `NSObject` and `@objc`)

Comment: I see another solution - we could make the app crash. That might be the best solution in some contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `MyProtocol` class is just an example. What I want to achieve is to provide a `UICollectionViewDataSource` implementation that wraps another `UICollectionViewDataSource` instance (the delegate) and executes some code before/after calling `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`. The implementation should just delegate the remaining methods of `UICollectionViewDataSource` to the delegate object. That's why I can't provide a default value.

Answer (score 1):

To start by addressing your question directly:

> how can I return the optional value that may be returned by delegate.opt?() and still conform to MyProtocol protocol?

For `req()` to propagate an optional value, it must be declared as returning an optional value. Your *implementation* of `req()` contains statements that return `Int?`, but this does not change the fact that the requirement was declared as `Int`.

---

It's worth nothing that your example here contains a few major oddities, none of which are inherently invalid, but are definitely contributing to the confusion here.

- You appear to be attempting to use the same protocol (`MyProtocol`) for two different purposes. While it would be very "clean" to unify your public and private interfaces' names into one, this doesn't actually provide any benefit to your code (the question you've posted is a good example as to why).

  ```
  @objc protocol MyProtocol {
      func req() -> Int?
  }
  @objc protocol MyProtocolOptionals {
      optional func req() -> Int
  }
  @objc class ProtocolWrapper : NSObject, MyProtocol {
      let delegate : MyProtocolOptionals
      func opt() -> Int? { return delegate.opt?() }
  }
  ```
- The Objective-C protocols in general, including the `optional` attribute, are implemented in Swift primarily for the benefit of older codebases designed around them. Ideally, new code will adopt Swift's native semantics. An alternative to `optional` methods, for example, would be a protocol extension that provides a default implementation of a method to conforming types that do not declare their own:

  ```
  protocol MyProtocolOptionals {
      func req() -> Int?
  }
  extension MyProtocolOptionals {
      func req() -> Int? { return nil }
  }

  @objc MyNonImplementing: MyProtocolOptionals {
  }

  @objc MyImplementing: MyProtocolOptionals {
      func req() -> Int? { return true.hashValue }
  }
  ```

Comment: If I change `func opt() -> Int` to `func opt() -> Int?`, `ProtocolWrapper` will not conform to `MyProtocol`. So I can't do that.

Comment: I agree with you that the optional and required operations should be split into two different protocols. However, `MyProtocol` is a 3rd party protocol which I can't modify. Thank you for your help.